# setting pins on various ports in gpio LM3SD96

Tags: embedded, arm, gpio

I want to set a few pins in GPIO ports PA, PD, and PF on a Stellaris LM3S9D96.

I know the bit operation procedures needed to that, but I am confused on how to select different pins in ports PA, PD, etc. and `AND` them with appropriate masks. Could someone explain these operations to me?

Answer (score 0):

The ports on the Stellaris chips are pin addressable. This made really easy if you use the [StellarisWare Driver Library](http://www.ti.com/tool/sw-drl).

The [User Guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spmu019p/spmu019p.pdf) has a pretty good example of how to use the GPIO Library functions. From page 142-143:

> ## 9.3 Programming Example
>
> The following example shows how to use the GPIO API to initialize the GPIO, enable interrupts, read data from pins, and write data to pins.
>
> ```c
> int iVal;
>
> //
> // Register the port-level interrupt handler. This handler is the first
> // level interrupt handler for all the pin interrupts.
> //
> GPIOPortIntRegister(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, PortAIntHandler);
>
> //
> // Initialize the GPIO pin configuration.
> //
> // Set pins 2, 4, and 5 as input, SW controlled.
> //
> GPIOPinTypeGPIOInput(GPIO_PORTA_BASE,
>                      GPIO_PIN_2 | GPIO_PIN_4 | GPIO_PIN_5);
>
> //
> // Set pins 0 and 3 as output, SW controlled.
> //
> GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_3);
>
> //
> // Make pins 2 and 4 rising edge triggered interrupts.
> //
> GPIOIntTypeSet(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_2 | GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_RISING_EDGE);
>
> //
> // Make pin 5 high level triggered interrupts.
> //
> GPIOIntTypeSet(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_HIGH_LEVEL);
>
> //
> // Read some pins.
> //
> iVal = GPIOPinRead(GPIO_PORTA_BASE,
>                    (GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_2 | GPIO_PIN_3 |
>                     GPIO_PIN_4 | GPIO_PIN_5));
>
> //
> // Write some pins. Even though pins 2, 4, and 5 are specified, those pins
> // are unaffected by this write because they are configured as inputs. At
> // the end of this write, pin 0 will be a 0, and pin 3 will be a 1.
> //
> GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTA_BASE,
>              (GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_2 | GPIO_PIN_3 |
>               GPIO_PIN_4 | GPIO_PIN_5),
>              0xF8);
>
> //
> // Enable the pin interrupts.
> //
> GPIOPinIntEnable(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_2 | GPIO_PIN_4 | GPIO_PIN_5);
> ```